# WebForms - Pass Complex Array of Objects Using jQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, arrays, ajax

I want to pass a complex array of Objects, and evrey Object have an other 2 array of objects.

Example:

```
 [{"Item":{"ClientId":"2","Projects":[{"ProjectId":"81","TypeId":"8"}],"Types":[{"ProjectType":"2","ProjectName":"yty - موقع2 - aaaaaaaa"},{"ProjectType":"6","ProjectName":"yty - موقع - aaaaaaaa"}]}},{"Item":{"ClientId":"7","Projects":[{"ProjectId":"75","TypeId":"8"},{"ProjectId":"76","TypeId":"8"}],"Types":[{"ProjectType":"2","ProjectName":"mona - موقع2 - aaaaaaaa"}]}}]
```

jquery Code:

```
      $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            var array = [];
            var donatorId = $('.ddlDonators').val();

            $.each($('.cbxClient:checked'), function () {
                var obj = new Object();
                var item = new Object();
                var projectArray = [];
                var projTypeArray = [];
                var attrId = $(this).attr('id');
                var clientId = attrId.split('_')[1];

                $.each($('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .Project:checked'), function () {
                    var projObj = new Object();
                    projObj.ProjectId = $(this).val();
                    projObj.TypeId = $(this).attr('ProjectType');
                    projectArray.push(projObj);
                });

                $.each($('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .ProjectType:checked'), function () {
                    var projTypeObj = new Object();
                    projTypeObj.ProjectType = $(this).val();
                    projTypeObj.ProjectName = $(this).attr('name') + " - " + $('.ddlDonators option:checked').text();
                    projTypeArray.push(projTypeObj);
                });

                obj.ClientId = attrId.split('_')[1];
                obj.CProject = projectArray;
                obj.Types = projTypeArray;
                item.Item = obj;
                array.push(item);

                //ProjectType = $('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .ProjectType:checked').val();
                //ProjectName = $('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .ProjectType:checked').attr('name') + " - " + $('.ddlDonators option:checked').text();
                //ProjectId = $('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .Project:checked').val();
                //ProjectType = $('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .Project:checked').attr('ProjectType');

            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SaveProjects",
                traditional :true,
                data: "{'DonatorId':'" + donatorId + "','Items':'" + JSON.stringify(array) + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error')
                    //  alert(data.responseText)
                }
            });  // end of ajax  


            console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
        });
```

C# Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveProjects(int DonatorId, List<Item> Items)
{


}


public class Item
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public List<CProject> Projects { get; set; }
    public List<Type> Types { get; set; }
}

public class CProject
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
}
public class Types
{
    public int ProjectType { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is, while debugging I found out that the count of Items is 2, but the prop inside it = null !!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by prop inside, would be better if you post the result of your debug

Comment: @Soner Gönül , I mean that the count of Items is 2 whic i s correct, but the value of the properties is Empty, for Example the ClientId=0 and the Others is null !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have Done this thing
 First You have To Change Your Parameter in which you take List to String because you are passing json array into string by stringify

than DeserializeObject the main array and Find nested array by Following Code...

```
  [WebMethod]
 public static void SaveProjects(int DonatorId, String MainArray)
 {

  Dictionary<string, dynamic> mainDictionary = (Dictionary<string, dynamic>)deserializer.DeserializeObject(MainArray);

 Dictionary<string, object> masterData = mainDictionary["SubArray"] as Dictionary<string, object>;

 object[] objNestedarray= masterData ["NestedArrayName"] as object[];

  }
```

Hope Above Code Help You to get Solution...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Actualy it was my fault, the stucture of array in client not the same in server side, so the mapping failed, so simply I just commented the the item Object in the client side.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
            var array = [];
            var donatorId = $('.ddlDonators').val();

            $.each($('.cbxClient:checked'), function () {
                var obj = new Object();
               // var item = new Object();
                var projectArray = [];
                var projTypeArray = [];
                var attrId = $(this).attr('id');
                var clientId = attrId.split('_')[1];

                $.each($('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .Project:checked'), function () {
                    var projObj = new Object();
                    projObj.ProjectId = $(this).val();
                    projObj.TypeId = $(this).attr('ProjectType');
                    projectArray.push(projObj);
                });

                $.each($('.formPnl').find('.' + attrId).find('li .ProjectType:checked'), function () {
                    var projTypeObj = new Object();
                    projTypeObj.ProjectType = $(this).val();
                    projTypeObj.ProjectName = $(this).attr('name') + " - " + $('.ddlDonators option:checked').text();
                    projTypeArray.push(projTypeObj);
                });

                obj.ClientId = attrId.split('_')[1];
                obj.CProject = projectArray;
                obj.Types = projTypeArray;
               // item.Item = obj;
                array.push(obj);


            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SaveProjects",
                traditional :true,
                data: "{'DonatorId':'" + donatorId + "','Items':" + JSON.stringify(array) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error')
                    //  alert(data.responseText)
                }
            });  // end of ajax  


            console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
        });
```

Server Side:

```
   [WebMethod]
public static void SaveProjects(int DonatorId, List<Item> Items)
{


}



public class Item
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public List<CProject> CProject { get; set; }
    public List<Types> Types { get; set; }
}

public class CProject
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
}
public class Types
{
    public int ProjectType { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```